# Dynamics AX 2009 SSRS 2008 report mail subscrition

Tags: reporting-services, axapta, subscription, dynamics-ax-2009

I have some issues on creating mail subscriptions for AX SSRS reports.

I put integrated credentials in the report, but subscription still return exception:

> An error has occurred during report processing.

Report works in browser with values for report parameters.
From the log file i extracted the error:

```
e ERROR: An exception has occurred in data source 'AutoGen___Query'. Details: Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: Failed to close connection for data source 'AutoGen___Query'. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Container' threw an exception. ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.
processing!WindowsService_0!f48!11/15/2012-03:35:04:: i INFO: Some other thread has already aborted processing.
processing!WindowsService_0!f48!11/15/2012-03:35:04:: e ERROR: Throwing Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException: , Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ProcessingAbortedException: An error has occurred during report processing. ---> Microsoft.ReportingServices.ReportProcessing.ReportProcessingException: Query execution failed for dataset 'BankAccountParam'. ---> System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'Container' threw an exception. ---> System.Security.SecurityException: Request failed.
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---;
```

Can someone to help me with this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately in 2009 you will either have to re-write the report to avoid using the  data source 'AutoGen___Query' - business logic, AX queries, etc

Or Create a batch job to email the report out.